# How to apply the same preprocessing steps to a numpy array that keras applied to images during training?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, opencv, keras, deep-learning

## Problem Setup

1. I have a collection of `float32` numpy arrays (say: `(100, 100)` each) that belong to several classes.
2. I've created an image dataset from them by saving them to the disk (`DATA_SET_PATH`) using `matplotlib.image.imsave(<save_path.jpg>, array, cmap='gray')`
3. Then, I've trained a pretrained VGG model on that image dataset using the following.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input

augmenter = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = augmenter.flow_from_directory(
        <DATA_SET_PATH>,
        target_size=(224, 224),  # this is the input size that VGG model expects
        color_mode='rgb',
        ...  # other parameters
        )

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False,
                     weights='imagenet',
                     input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
                    )

# other model configurations ...
# ...

model.fit(train_generator , ...)
```

4. Now, in production, I am receiving a numpy array in the same format as in above (1) and I want to obtain the prediction for that single numpy array using `model.predict()`.

## Question

So, in this setup, how can I ensure a single numpy array (`input`) would transform to the state of a model input tensor during training?

### What I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


input= np.random.randn(100, 100).astype(np.float32)  # sample input array

# first resize the array
input = cv2.resize(input, (224, 224), cv2.INTER_AREA)

# make this has three channels (because VGG model has expected so during the training)
input = np.stack([input] * 3, axis=-1)

# pass through the respective preprocessing function
input = preprocess_input(input)
```

When I pass this to `model.predict()` after expanding the dimensions, the predictions are obviously wrong, despite having good performance during training.

I think this is due to the fact that the above `input` being *different* than what the `model.input` has received during training. If needed, I can save the `input` array to an image as in above (2), but I want to know the next steps that keras would apply on to it.

#### Edit:

Based on the insight by @Lescurel in a comment and looking the source of the [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py), I've used the the [`load_img()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L261-L296) function and got this working by saving the array to an image and then loading it (to reproduce step 2 above and to make sure the `preprocessing_function` gets the values in the range 0-255).

Here's how I got it to work:

```
input= np.random.randn(100, 100).astype(np.float32)  # sample input array

# save `input` to an image and load it
temp_path = "temp_path.jpg"
matplotlib.image.imsave(temp_path, input, cmap='gray')
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(temp_path,
                                            color_mode='rgb',
                                            target_size=(224, 224)
                                        )
# convert to an array
input = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)

input = preprocess_input(input)

# the above `input` is passed to the model after adding the extra dimension.
# ...
```

For my use case, I would still prefer to  avoid saving this to an image and directly transform the numpy array to `preprocessing_function` by ensuring its values are in (0, 255) range, but that will be the scope of another question :)

Comment: I’m trying to understand the problem. So, you applied some preprocessing to your images and trained the CNN with the preprocessed images. Now, you are testing the CNN, but you are passing the test images *without* the same preprocessing stage. Now, the problem is that the CNN is miss-predicting the input. Is that right? If so, you must run the images through the same preprocessing pipeline you use during training, otherwise you are giving the CNN completely different data.

Comment: @stateMachine yes. The question is asking about *how* to make sure that an image (numpy array) to predict go through the same preprocessing steps as they did in the training. If this was a custom data generator, I would know the exact steps that were done. But, I'm using keras' `flow_from_directory` as shown above. For example, I have a `target_size` parameter in there. So, what image resizing method does `flow_from_directory` uses and what `dtype` of images do they expect in each of the step?

Comment: @stateMachine another example: when `flow_from_directory` reads images, what method does it use (is it `opencv.imread`, `skimage.io`, `PIL`'s `Image` or something else?).

Comment: @akilat90 you load the image (in training time) in  RGB, and that's why you should also convert to `BGRtoRGB` after reading the image using `cv2` in inference time. And also, if you rescale your samples in training time by (`1/ 255.`) then you should also ensure that in inference time.

Comment: @M.Innat Thank you. I don't see how it's relevant for this scenario though. My inputs at the prediction time are already numpy arrays and they represent grayscale images. Because the model expects a 3D input, I'm stacking the same image thrice to make it an input with three channels. Also, 1/255 wasn't applied anywhere during the training. See, "What I tried" section above to see what I'm doing at the prediction time.

Comment: You set `color_mode` to RGB, don't you?

Comment: @M.Innat yes, I did. How is that relevant? (As I've mentioned in my question, I need to do that because the VGG model expects a 3-channel input. So the same grayscale image gets cloned thrice and gets stacked on top of each other when `color_mode=rgb`).

Comment: `I have a collection of float32 numpy arrays (say: (100, 100) each) that belong to several classes.` So I assume that they have the same range as images (values between 0 and 255)? Because that's the assumption made by `preprocess_input`.

Comment: @Lescurel Thank you for bringing that up! The input wasn't in [0,255] but `preprocess_input` wasn't raising an error either :(  I was also able to get the predictions to make sense by looking into the source and using keras' preprocessing functions instead of opencv operations I've done. See my Edit above.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of community providing solution here

> Based on the insight by @Lescurel in a comment and looking the source
> of the [tf.keras.preprocessing.image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py), I've used the the [load_img()](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.5.0/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L261-L296)
> function and got this working by saving the array to an image and then
> loading it (to reproduce step 2 above and to make sure the
> `preprocessing_function` gets the values in the range 0-255).
>
> Here's how I got it to work:
>
> ```
> input= np.random.randn(100, 100).astype(np.float32)  # sample input array
>
> # save `input` to an image and load it
> temp_path = "temp_path.jpg"
> matplotlib.image.imsave(temp_path, input, cmap='gray')
> img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(temp_path,
>                                             color_mode='rgb',
>                                             target_size=(224, 224)
>                                         )
> # convert to an array
> input = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
>
> input = preprocess_input(input)
>
> # the above `input` is passed to the model after adding the extra dimension.
> # ...
> ```

(paraphrased from akilat90)